# Parse.com what is the timezone of cloud code

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, timezone

I have a js script in cloud code. And I need to send a notification to my user at some hour of the day.

Therefore I'd like to know :
 1. what is the timezone of cloud code server ? 
 2. how do I use timeZone property of installation in the JS SDK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything in the cloud is GMT.   Best approach is to keep GMT everywhere, except on the UI.  Notification is a sort of UI.  After a user is created, work out the GMT time that you wish to push, and use that.

[Here's a decent article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10087819/convert-date-to-another-timezone-in-javascript) on timezone conversion.